# JQuery each: проблема организации зависимых select

Tags: jquery, массивы, json

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь сделать некий функционал для удобности организации зависимых выпадающих списков.

Т.е. чтобы не копипастить один и тот же код у которого будут только разные названия.

В общем не получается вот что [пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qXdm8/4/)

Специально на `jsfiddle`, чтобы было понятно.

Функция `changeSelectList` как видно принимает три параметра

1. **`id`** из первого `select`(не важен в
       данном случан)
2. **`select_value`** - это `ID`, который будет
       во втором селексе в `option value`
3. **`select_name`** - это название которое
       будет в `option`

Если же в `each` я делаю

```
sselect.append('<option value="'+this.type+'">'+this.color+'</option>');
```

Где **`type` и `color`** (это ключи в массиве), то все норм и мне выводит как положено.

Если я пытаюсь использовать аргументы функции

```
sselect.append('<option value="'+this.select_value+'">'+this.select_name+'</option>');
```

то в ответ получаю `undefined`.  Я в JS совсем мало понимаю, не серчайте)

Нагуглись, почему не работает не получилось.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: вы же смотрели чему равен this, это элемент массива из json, не очень понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать, и чем this.type не нравится

Comment: [так надо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qXdm8/6/) ?

Comment: Да. Не подумал совсем про квадратные скобки.

Большое спасибо @eicto

Создайте, пожалуйста ответ, я выберу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, вам нужно выбрать значение `this` , основываясь на значении `select_value` в js это делается квадратными скобками -  `this[select_value]`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.